# Visual Studio does not run function after first execution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, cache-control

In my c# file, I have a line:

```
if (request.Message.Version != Manager.Version)
```

On the first execution, it does go to `Manager()` and executes the code in the function. However, if I run the program afterwards, it just skips calling the `Manager()` and continues running the line after it. Interestingly, I found that if I restart the visual studio, it does run that `Manager()` function again.

The Manager() Function is for assigning values from configuration appsettings to my queue

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I guess Manager is a static-class?
I had the same problem once that it doesn't get cleaned from the cache. Try to "clean the build" before running it again. Helped in my case

Comment: There's not really enough detail here to accurately help you. But since your tags say you're doing something with a cache maybe one of the "Version" numbers is changing in the cache (or static class) somehow. And then when you restart VS the cache is cleared and it works again. Are you setting the "Version" number in the function call?

Comment: @Richard: Cache? Clean Build? Not really. A static constructor is executed once per application life time. That's how it is supposed to be. There is no "cache" involved and there is nothing wrong a Clean Build could fix.

Comment: Richard, Chris and Daniel,all genius!! you are all right, thanks so much. :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My crystal ball says that `Manager()` is a static constructor:

```
static Manager()
{
    // some code
}
```

The whole point of static constructors is that they are run only once per application lifetime, so everything is working as expected here.

Further reading:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx

Comment: Could also be the constructor of a singleton, which is the same general idea as this.

Comment: @Daniel Hi hi Daniel, could you turn on your crystall ball again and see if you have any idea on this please? Thanks thanks : )  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410227/windows-service-not-started-in-visual-studio